# Display Image along with Pixel values channel by channel with Python open cv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

[image]Please provide code, how to view pixel values in a image form. as shown in picture,
I am looking a python code, not from Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

We may use [numpy.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy-savetxt):

Assume `img` is a NumPy array that represents a grayscale image.
Saving `img` into text file (as 2D table):

```
np.savetxt('img.txt', img, fmt='%3d')
```

---

In case the image is BGR pixel format, save the three channels:

```
np.savetxt('blue_ch.txt', img[:, :, 0], fmt='%3d')
np.savetxt('green_ch.txt', img[:, :, 1], fmt='%3d')
np.savetxt('red_ch.txt', img[:, :, 2], fmt='%3d')
```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Draw the digit 8 on 30x40 grayscale image:
width, height = 30, 40
img = np.full((height, width), 60, np.uint8)
cv2.putText(img, '8', (width//2-10, height//2+10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, 255, 2)

np.savetxt('img.txt', img, fmt='%3d')

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Content of `img.txt`:

```
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255  60 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 255 255 255 255 255 255 255  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
 60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60
```

---

**Creating an image with drawn pixel values:**

In case you intention is to create an image (not a text file), we have to use a for loop, and draw each pixel as text using `cv2.putText`.

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Draw the digit 8 on 30x40 grayscale image:
width, height = 30, 40
img = np.full((height, width), 60, np.uint8)
cv2.putText(img, '8', (width//2-10, height//2+10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, 255, 2)

np.savetxt('img.txt', img, fmt='%3d')

text_size = cv2.getTextSize(' 255', cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1)
w, h = text_size[0]
h +=8  # Add some vertical space.

im = np.full((height*h, width*w), 0, np.uint8)

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        p = img[row, col]  # Get pixel value
        x = col * w
        y = row * h + (h-1)  # y is the bottom corner of the text position
        text = str(p)
        cv2.putText(im, text, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 255, 1)


im = cv2.resize(im, [width*w//2, height*h//2])  # Make it smaller

cv2.imwrite('im.png', im)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('im', im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

Play with the font for getting a more esthetic result.
You may use other library (not OpenCV) that supports higher quality text drawing.